Sort by title - Shopify
{% for line in subtotal_line_items **| sort: "line.product.title"** %}


 {% if line.quantity < line.quantity %}
          {% capture line_display %}
          {{ line.quantity }} di {{ line.quantity }}
          {% endcapture %}
          {% else %}
          {% assign line_display = line.quantity %}
          {% endif %}

etc. etc.
DOESNT WORK - this code its a part of email confirmation order in shopify... i need sort the products by title in email for internal staff
Doesnt WORK! Someone can solve me the problem? its 8 hours than searching online a solution,
Thank in advance

did you try assign to another variable?
{% assign items | sort: "product.title" %}
